# Use #each with argument in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm new with the Meteor framework and I'm trying to show some data with meteor + mongo + spacebars. The problem is that I might need to use one argument with the spacebar, #each, and it does not allow it.

My code:

$ file.js

```
  Template.home.helpers({
      places: function() {
          return Places.find();
      }
  });

  Template.content.helpers({
    images: function() {
        return Images.find({});
     }
  });
```

$ file.html

```
<template name="home">    
    {{#each places}}
        {{>content}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="content">
    <li>{{name}} - {{date}}</li>
    {{#each images}}
        <img src="{{this.url}}">    
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

What I want to do - and it didn't work - is to use an argument in the Template.content.helper function, like below:

```
  Template.content.helpers({
    images: function(ARG) {
        return Images.find({place: ARG});
     }
  });
```

and in the html file would be

```
<template name="content">
    <li>{{name}} - {{date}}</li>
    {{#each images {{name}} }}
        <img src="{{this.url}}">    
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Do you guys have any idea how to show the information correctly? I don't want to show all the information (images) for each place. I want to show the images correspondent for that place only...

Thanks in advance, 
Marcus

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))` inside the helper that receives the arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the helper's implementation can access the current data context as this, you need not pass `{{name}}` as an argument. In stead, access `{{name}}` in the helper with `this.name` .

**Jade**

```
<template name="content">
  <li>{{name}} - {{date}}</li>
  {{#each images}}
    <img src="{{this.url}}">    
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Template.content.helpers({
  images: function() {
    place = this.name;
    return Images.find({place: place});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I was able to do what I wanted with the following code:

file.html

```
<template name="content">
    <li>{{name}} - {{date}}</li>   
    {{#each images name}}
        <img src="{{this.url}}">    
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

(which means that I had to remove the double brackets)

and then in the file.js

```
Template.content.helpers({
    images: function(location) {
        console.log(location);
        return Images.find({"metadata.location": location});
    }
  });
```

I hope it helps someone else as well.